# Tensorflow: None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using a very small model for testing purposes using tensorflow 2.3 and keras.
Looking at my terminal, I get the following warning:

```
I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:118] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 1)
```

However, the code works as expected. But what does this message mean?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an error message. The `I` at the beginning of the message means this is an informational log message.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question

Answer (score 81, accepted):

MLIR is being used as another solution to implementing and optimizing Tensorflow logic. This informative message is *benign* and is saying MLIR was not being used. This is expected as in TF 2.3, the MLIR based implementation is still being developed and proven, so end users are generally not expected to use the MLIR implementation and are instead expected to use the non-MLIR feature complete implementation.

Update: [still experimental](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_mlir_graph_optimization) on version 2.9.1. On the docs it is written:

> DO NOT USE, DEV AND TESTING ONLY AT THE MOMENT.

Comment: Is this still valid for TF 2.4 ?

Comment: What about TF2.5 ?

Comment: ...and what about TF 2.6?

Comment: Try this: with tf.Session(graph=G,config=tf.ConfigProto(
      allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)) as sess:

Comment: @daniel451: The official documentation says: `DO NOT USE, DEV AND TESTING ONLY AT THE MOMENT.`

Comment: ...and now what about TF 2.8?

Comment: so, how can I enable an "MLIR optimization"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `verbose=1` in your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).