# TF 2.4.1 Hanging while training using the pretrained object detection model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am fairly new to TF and ML in general, so I have relied heavily on the documentation and tutorials provided by TF. I have been following along with the [Tensorflow 2.0 Objection Detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) tutorial to the letter and have encountered an issue while training: everytime I run the training script `model_main_tf2.py`, it always hangs after the output:
`I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)` after a number of depreciation warnings. I have tried many different ways of fixing this, including modifying the train script and pipeline.config files. My dataset isn't very large, less than 100 images with a max of 15 labels per image.

useful info:
Python 3.8.0 
Tensorflow 2.4.4 (Non GPU) 
Windows 10 Pro

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow: None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886762/tensorflow-none-of-the-mlir-optimization-passes-are-enabled-registered-1)

Comment: Maybe try with TensorFlow version 2.2 and if possible, python 3.6?